# error when trying to install scip

Tags: software-installation

I try to install scip package in Ubuntu 16.04
but I encounter this error:

```
"bin/scip-3.2.1.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx" not found.
       This is needed by ./check.sh to work. Check your
       $PATH variable or install the tool "bin/scip-.2.1.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.s"
```

What should I do?

Comment: How were you trying to install it? Where did you get the download from?

Answer (score 0):

If you ran `make LPS=cpx` or [another linear solver](http://scip.zib.de/doc-2.0.2/html/MAKE.html) other than soplex and tried to run `make test` then you also have to write `make test LPS=cpx` or the abbr. of the linear solver you used.